# Artifact for contract "TestSafeProtocolRegistryUnrestricted" not found

Tags: safe-core

I'm trying to deploy a new plugin and following the repo [Safe-core-protocol demo contract](https://github.com/5afe/safe-core-protocol-demo/tree/main/contracts  "safe-core-protocol-demo"

plugin is deployed but when I try to register plugin with command `yarn register-plugin goerli`

getting following error

Error HH700: Artifact for contract "TestSafeProtocolRegistryUnrestricted" not found.

Comment: For reporting bugs, please create an issue in the corresponding repository.